# Fine tuning on either Google Cloud Vision, Microsoft Azure Computer Vision API or Amazon Text Extract

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, google-cloud-platform, computer-vision, text-extraction

I need to transcribe a large number of Handwritten documents. I tried to use cloud services from either Google, Amazon, and Microsoft. Namely:

- https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/computer-vision/
- https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/handwriting
- https://aws.amazon.com/textract/

Unfortunately, none of them achieved good enough results. I suspect it is because my documents have a weird handwriting style, and as a result, the networks struggle a lot.
I searched whether I could fine-tune (with manually transcribed data), but I have not found anything online, so as a last resort, I ask here.

If it is possible to fine-tune one of these models, could you please point me some resources?

Comment: Google Cloud Vision you cannot provide your own input other than to specify the input language and change between standard and document text.

Comment: Thank you so, the last hope is for Amazon Textract

Comment: I don't believe Amazon Textract can do it either -- Google is the leader in language based research followed by Azure, so with neither of them offering it there is probably a good reason. My guess is that it would require too much input data to customize a model and because OCR as it stands works fairly well for most users it wouldn't pay off to spend the time on it. My best advice is work on trimming your document to specific text chunks and try out the different models such as [Document AI](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/document-ai) which should help you get closer.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, with Azure Cognitive Services with Computer Vision you cannot upload your own data to train the API to recognise the handwriting in your documents I'm afraid. I can't comment on the other offerings from AWS and Google I'm afraid, but certainly not for Azure.